# Array of custom type elements keys

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get a response from PHP of a multidimensional array of objects like this

```
[CartItems] => Array
(
    [15] => stdClass Object
    (
        [key] => 15
        [value] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Item] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [quantity] => 7
            )
        )
    )
    [25] => stdClass Object
    (
        [key] => 25
        [value] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Item] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [quantity] => 5
            )
        )
    )
    [26] => stdClass Object
    (
        [key] => 26
        [value] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Item] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [quantity] => 5
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I tried  an Array type in the WSDL file

```
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfProducts">
                    <xsd:complexContent>
                        <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                            <xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="Product[]"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:complexContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
```

The main point here that I want to return the array 'CartItems' with an accessible elements directly using  keys

I don't rely on this solution particularly, I just want to access every object directly without walking through all the array to find the desired object.